# Package project to WAR with SBT (Scala Build Tool)

Tags: scala, maven, war, sbt

I have a Maven multi-project which I want to convert to SBT:
This is what it looks like:

parent project:
+ module_1  --> jar
+ module_2  --> jar
+ module_3.dependsOn(module_1,module_2) --> jar
+ **module_4**.dependsOn(module_3) ***--> war***

**module_4** is configured to be build as a **WAR** with `<packaging>war</packaging>`
in it's pom.xml so it can be deployed later to a web application server.

I have configured this project within a single (project/build.scala) scala file. I don't want to deploy **module_4** to a web server (yet) I just need it's artifact as a **WAR** file.
Perhaps I don't understand the [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Artifacts.html) (most likely), but when I try to write it in the scala configuration SBT doesn't compile:

```
lazy val snowRest = Project(id = "sc-ws",
           base = file("sc-ws"),
           settings = buildSettings ++ Seq (libraryDependencies ++= snowCannonRest) ++ Seq(artifact in (Compile, packageWar) ~= { (art: Artifact) => art.copy(`type` = "war", extension = "war")})
           ) dependsOn(snowCannonBase)
```

and failes with this message:

```
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]                               artifact in (Compile, packageWar) ~= { (art: Artifact) => art.copy(`type` = "war", extension = "war")})
[error]                                                     ^
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: While I partially managed to create a war with the sbt-web-plugin:https://github.com/JamesEarlDouglas/xsbt-web-plugin It still not complete, when I finally manage build the war I want I will publish the entire solution here as an answer if none will be given before that.
Here is the second question regarding war packaging - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461147/simple-build-tool-sbt-package-war